# CertificateVerificationFailed while trying to get Citrix License Information

Tags: powershell, citrix, xenapp, xendesktop

**What I'm trying to acheive:**

I'm trying to get the license information from my citrix. For a simple first step, I tried to run this code: (I've replaced the server url with "xxxx" since I'm not allowed to make them public).

```
Add-PSSnapin citrix.*
$Lics = Get-LicInventory -AdminAddress "https://xxxx.com:8083"
$Lics
```

**This results in the following error:**

> Get-LicInventory : CertificateVerificationFailed At line:3 char:9
>   + $Lics = Get-LicInventory -AdminAddress "https://xxxx ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Get-LicInventory:String) [Get-LicInventory],
>   InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Citrix.PowerShell.LicensingAdminStatus.CertificateVerificationFailed,Citrix.Licensing.Admin
>   .SDK.Commands.GetLicInventoryCommand

**What I've done till now:**

I don't know what this error means. I searched for `CertificateVerificationFailed` on Google but haven't found anything.

I'm sure the URI is the correct one. I run:

`get-configsite`

and copied the URI from there. The port is correct and as far as I know it has to use HTTPS for the communication. When trying to do it with only `http://` I get a `CommunicationError`, so kinda sure the HTTPS is the right choice. I really don't what I'm doing wrong here.

May someone of you had the same problem or have an idea what I could try else. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Do you have a self-signed certificate on the server you're querying (assuming it's yours)?

Comment: What if you try to paste obtained admin address to web browser? Will you get any error?